# FastAPI async routes deadlock bug when using infinite loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, fastapi, python-3.10

I am experiencing an issue with FastAPI where the application gets deadlocked when using an infinite loop in an **async** route. Here is a simplified version of my FastAPI application (fastapi_test.py):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import random

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/hello")
async def hello():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

# This route works normally and /hello route keeps working
@app.get("/normal")
def route_normal():
    while True:
        print({"route_normal": random.randint(0, 10)})

# This route causes a whole application deadlock
@app.get("/async")
async def route_async():
    while True:
        print({"route_async": random.randint(0, 10)})

# requirements
# pip install fastapi uvicorn[standard]
```

When I call the `/normal` route, the application keeps working normally. However, when I call the `/async` route, the application gets deadlocked, and no routes work anymore. I am running the application using the following command:

```
uvicorn fastapi_test:app --workers 1
```

I have observed that this issue occurs when using an infinite loop inside an async route. Is there a known limitation or recommended way to handle infinite loops in async routes to avoid deadlocks?

I also benchmarked async and normal /hello route and got ~50% better results for **async** version.

```
ab -n 100000 -c 1000 http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello
```

All this is really confusing for me.

python 3.10
fastapi==0.104.1

I appreciate any guidance or insights into resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: An infinite loop in an async function should be async. If that's not possible then either use a sync func or put an `await asyncio.sleep(0)` somewhere in the loop to give other tasks a chance to run. see this https://arc.net/l/quote/zudiovyd

Answer (score 2):

this async + the `while True` loop, is causing python to lock as its trying to process the loop and not being able to switch to the other interal process.

```
@app.get("/async")
async def route_async():
```

this can be fixed by using background tasks

```
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks

@app.get("/async")
async def route_async(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    def background_task():
        while True:
            print({"route_async": random.randint(0, 10)})

    background_tasks.add_task(background_task)
    return {"message": "Background task started"}
```

full code

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks
import random

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/hello")
async def hello():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

@app.get("/normal")
def route_normal():
    while True:
        print({"route_normal": random.randint(0, 10)})

@app.get("/async")
async def route_async(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    def background_task():
        while True:
            print({"route_async": random.randint(0, 10)})

    background_tasks.add_task(background_task)
    return {"message": "Background task started"}
```

## Alternative Solution

allow your async function to sleep

```
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI
import random

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/hello")
async def hello():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

@app.get("/normal")
def route_normal():
    while True:
        print({"route_normal": random.randint(0, 10)})

@app.get("/async")
async def route_async():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0) # do a sleep here so that the main thread can do its magic, at least once per loop, changing the sleep duration will allow the main thread to process other threads longer, please read up more on the specifics
        print({"route_async": random.randint(0, 10)})
```

Comment: I still wonder why non-async routes are not deadlocking and how can I return result of the background task in route if it's not an infinite loop, but just long running cpu job?

Comment: you wont have that issue with a long running cpu job, as it will eventually return. but the connection request my timeout

Comment: The job itself locking other routes until it finished. This only happens when route is async. 
@dean-van-greunen

Comment: @tombreplacer FastApi will run sync functions in a separate threadpool so they don't block. While the async routes get run on the main thread (since we assume they won't block). So if you have a blocking async route you will now block the main thread.

Comment: @fantafles yes, it will block the main thread, thats why background tasks exist, to solve this very issue

Comment: @fanta-fles Do I understand correctly that the reason to make routes async is that it requires less work to allocate resources? Is that why my benchmark with the /hello route performed better when it was marked as async?

Comment: @tombreplacer Yes you remove the overhead of separate threads, but you now have to make sure your code is non-blocking which makes it a bit more difficult.

Comment: see my updated answer with suggestions from @fantafles

Comment: @tombreplacer async is called cooperative multitasking - your code has to cooperate with the eventloop when it can - i.e. when it doesn't have anything to do, it gives up CPU time while waiting for other resources (IO). When you're not cooperating, nothing else will run; and the overhead of having thousands of async functions waiting for IO is far better than trying to have a threadpool of the same size.